# Replace zeros of array with last non-zero value in Amibroker

Tags: amibroker

I have an array that looks like this;

```
arr_with_zeros = [1 0 0 2 0 0 3 0 0 6 0 0 8 0 0]
```

I want to replace the zeros with the last non-zero value in the array. The new array should look like this;

```
arr_non_zeros = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 6 6 6 8 8 8]
```

This is the code I wrote.

```
arr_non_zeros = ValueWhen(True, arr_with_zeros, n=1);
```

It does not work. arr_non_zeros has the same contents as arr_with_zeros. Can someone help? Thank you.

I am using Amibroker ver6.30.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [IIF](https://www.amibroker.com/guide/afl/iif.html)

```
arr_new = iif(arr_non_zeros == 0, ref(arr_non_zeros,-1), arr_non_zeros);
```